# Is it true that the mobius function $\mu(\frac{n}{d})=(-1)^k\mu(d)$?

Tags: number-theory

Is it true that the mobius function $\mu(\frac{n}{d})=(-1)^k\mu(d)$? and what does the $k$ represent?

I am sorry for the simplicity of this questions, I am sure I have read this somewhere but I cannot seem to find the source at the moment.

Comment: What is $\mu$ ?

Comment: The Mobius function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is not true if $n$ is not squarefree.

If $n$ is squarefree, say the product of $k$ primes, and $d$ is the product of $j$ primes, then 
$$
  \mu(n/d)
  = (-1)^{k-j}
  = (-1)^{k+j}
  = (-1)^k \mu(d) .
$$